# accessibility of variables within for statement when using out of it

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[Using colaboratory, language : Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0llCl.png)

I thought the variable i should only bee accessible within the for statement and thus this code should result in error. Why is this not an error? Is it the issue of development environment? Is this due to the flexibility of Python?

Comment: "I thought the variable i should only bee accessible within the for statement" well, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the flexibility of python, the variables you declared inside of a loop is accessible outside of the loop as well.